# PHPUnit Mocking View Helper ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

I created a View Helper :

```
class SousMenuContrat extends AbstractHelper
{
    private $maiContratService;

    public function __construct(
        FMaiContratService $maiContratService,
    ) {
        $this->maiContratService                = $maiContratService;
    }

    public function __invoke($iMaiContratId, $sActive)
    {
        $oContrat = $this->maiContratService->selectById($iMaiContratId);

        return $this->getView()->partial('maintenance/sousmenucontrat', array(
            'oContrat'         => $oContrat
        ));
    }
}
```

So now I need to test it, with PHPUnit :

```
class SousMenuContratTest extends TestCase
{
    private $myService;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $maiContratService = $this->getMockBuilder('Maintenance\Service\Model\FMaiContratService')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $oContrat = new FMaiContrat();
        $stub = $this->returnValue($oContrat);
        $maiContratService->expects($this->any())->method('selectById')->will($stub);
        $this->myService = new SousMenuContrat(
            $maiContratService
        );
    }

    public function testInvoque()
    {
        $this->myService->__invoke(2, 'contrat');
    }
}
```

But the test sends an error, because the test doesn't know :

> $this->getView()->partial();

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Advise for future projects: Don't name your classes etc. in your mother language. It is good practice to keep the entire code in English. This way, everyone can understand it and because all the functions are in English as well, you only have one language in your code. (Our trainees always get in trouble when they use German in their code ;-) )

Comment: I know, but it's internal convention :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test, you need to mock the renderer returned by `getView()`:

```
    /** @var PhpRenderer|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $rendererMock */
    $rendererMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $rendererMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method("partial")
        ->with(array(
            'maintenance/sousmenucontrat',
            array('oContrat' => new FMaiContrat()),
        ));
    $this->myService->setView($rendererMock);
```

Best solution would be to use the same `FMaiContrat` object you instantiate in `setUp()` in `with()`, but in this case, this works as well.

**Edit:** And the complete test code will look like this:

```
class SousMenuContratTest extends TestCase
{
    private $myService;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $maiContratService = $this->getMockBuilder('Maintenance\Service\Model\FMaiContratService')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $oContrat = new FMaiContrat();
        $stub = $this->returnValue($oContrat);
        $maiContratService->expects($this->any())->method('selectById')->will($stub);
        $this->myService = new SousMenuContrat(
            $maiContratService
        );
    }

    public function testInvoque()
    {
        /** @var PhpRenderer|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $rendererMock */
        $rendererMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $rendererMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method("partial")
            ->with(array(
                'maintenance/sousmenucontrat',
                array('oContrat' => new FMaiContrat()),
            ));
        $this->myService->setView($rendererMock);
        $this->myService->__invoke(2, 'contrat');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I got a failure :(

1) MaintenanceTest\Service\Model\SousMenuContratTest::testInvoque
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:partial> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

Comment: Good, it means the mock works ;-) I edited my answer, the complete code might help.

Comment: I'd need to see your code but debugging further problems is not the purpose of an answer. I opened a chat room for this matter:
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91564/room-for-amelie-and-storyteller
Please paste your helper and test code in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following setup if you want to just use ZF2 classes and then just mock your dependency in SousMenuContrat constructor

```
protected function setUp()
{
   $maiContratService = $this->getMockBuilder('Maintenance\Service\Model\FMaiContratService')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $oContrat = new FMaiContrat($maiContratService);
    $stub = $this->returnValue($oContrat);
    $maiContratService->expects($this->any())->method('selectById')->will($stub);

    Doctype::unsetDoctypeRegistry();

    $this->helper = new SousMenuContrat();
    $this->renderer = new PhpRenderer;
    $this->viewHelperManager = $this->renderer->getHelperPluginManager();
    $config  = new HelperConfig();
    $config->configureServiceManager($this->viewHelperManager);
    $this->helper->setView($this->renderer);

    parent::setUp();
}
```